# Create several AWS accounts and populate them with services using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

The only CDK example I've seen that sets up an organizational structure and creates accounts is the [AWS Bootstrap Kit Examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-bootstrap-kit-examples/blob/d85403ea5010f9fcb0e02aad49b22b32c2117dd7/source/1-SDLC-organization/bin/sdlc-organization.ts#L32-L70), where you pass in an array of OUs to create, e.g.:

```js
const nestedOU = [
    {
        name: 'SharedServices',
        accounts: [
            {
                name: 'CICD',
                type: AccountType.CICD
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'SDLC',
        accounts: [
            {
                name: 'Dev',
                type: AccountType.PLAYGROUND
            },
            {
                name: 'Staging',
                type: AccountType.STAGE,
                stageName: 'staging',
                stageOrder: 1,
                hostedServices: ['ALL']
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However this approach only creates empty accounts, and doesn't let you populate them with services because they don't return the new account IDs.

On the other hand, all the AWS examples that deploy services to multiple accounts assume that they accounts already exist. For example [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cdk-credential-plugin/) defines a stack and deploys it to two *existing* accounts:

```js
const dev = { account: 'REPLACE_WITH_DEV_ACCOUNT_ID', region: 'us-east-2' }
const prod = { account: 'REPLACE_WITH_PROD_ACCOUNT_ID', region: 'us-east-1' }

new SampleApp(app, 'devSampleApp', { env: dev });
new SampleApp(app, 'prodSampleApp', { env: prod });
```

Is there a way in CDK to create an entire multi-account stack, and populate it with services, all within the same CDK stack?

Answer (score 2):

The creation and bootstrapping of new accounts is unfortunately not yet supported in cdk, probably because cloudformation also wasn't very strong there. You can create a bunch if custom resources for creating and deleting accounts and deploy them to the master account though. CdK does have a nice construct for single cli-call custom resources like CreateOrganizationalUnit.
However, referencing the outputs of these calls is still hard since cross-account/cross-region references are also poorly supported. This makes me very skeptical that this is the way to go for now, until these issues are solved.

If you aren't bound by CDK, i think the org-formation open source project does a nice job in providing the features that cloudformation is missing. You can set up an organizational structure and reference values cross-account. You can even deploy "tasks" to the new accounts which can be a cloudformation stack, a cdk app or some other predefines common tasks.

Also tools similar to CDK like pulumi or CDK for terraform have better organizations support and allow you to do everything in the same app.